# Camera does not turn on when laptop is locked when using howdy (facial recognition)

Tags: login-screen, webcam, camera

I am attempting to use the *howdy* package to attempt facial recognition. Though I am able to use its functionality in terminal, while using *sudo* commands, I cannot do so while logging in. It seems my laptop camera does not turn on when I attempt to login. At the login screen, *howdy* does post a message saying "Attempting facial recognition", but I feel that it cannot get access to the camera in a locked state. Is there a way around this, perhaps, by granting the camera privileges to turn on when the laptop is locked, or anything else?

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and the howdy package I speak of, can be found here: https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy

I would appreciate any useful insights into this. Thank you!